# different behavior of process.argv

Tags: node.js

i am new in node js just try to finish [learnyounode](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode) workshops

when i run following code by "node filename.js" it gave me error

```
fs.js:418
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
```

but it working fine with "learnyounode run filename.js"

```
var fs = require('fs')
        var file = process.argv[2]

        fs.readFile(file, function (err, contents) {
          // fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', callback) can also be used
          var lines = contents.toString().split('\n').length - 1
          console.log(lines)
        })
```

what is wrong with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`learnyounode run filename.js` runs `node filename.js {{fileToBeRead}}` which is to say you need to give it a command line argument or process.argv[2] will be undefined which is causing `fs.readFile(undefined, . . .` to throw an error.